# recursive binary search in ruby

Tags: ruby, recursion, binary-search

I've been learning some algorithms and I can't find the reason why my method is failing. if you could look at the code and shed some light as to why that is happening. I would truly appreciate it.

I'm trying to write a method that would binary search an array recursively and so far that is all my code.

```
 def recursive_binary_search(arr, target)
   max_index = arr.length - 1
   mid_index = max_index / 2

   if arr[mid_index] > target
     new_arr = arr[0..(mid_index - 1)]
     recursive_binary_search(new_arr, target)
   elsif arr[mid_index] < target
     new_arr = arr[(mid_index + 1)..max_index]
     recursive_binary_search(new_arr, target)
   else
     return mid_index
   end
 end
```

The error I keep getting is `undefined method '>' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: It'd help a lot if you strip out the line numbers in pasted code so that we can build on it and make a solution wtithout having to do that.

Comment: Remember that when trying to solve problems like this it's usually best to create a one or more test cases first and code second. Your test cases help define the parameters of the problem you're trying to solve, and will identify when you have a solution.

Comment: An example of `arr`, an example of `target` and the related expected output could help people giving an answer.

Comment: Here are a couple of suggestions about the construction of questions. 1. State your question first, in words (reverse your first two paragraphs). 2. Readers may wish to run your code, with or without modifications. The first step is to cut-and-paste. Here a second step is needed to remove line numbers. It's best to present code only, no line numbers, IRB prompts and so on. 3. It would have been helpful had you given an example that resulted in the exception you mention...

Comment: ...When you give an example (more generally), make everything a valid Ruby object (no `...(etc.)`, for example, make the example as succinct as possible, assign a variable to each input object (e.g., `arr = [1,2,3]`) so readers can refer to those variables in answers and comments without having to define them, and show the desired result (as a Ruby object).

Answer (score 4):

I was unable to reproduce the exception reported by the OP (as the data that produced the exception was not given in the question), but the main problem is that, because `max_index` is computed from `arr`, and `arr` is constantly getting smaller, the index returned by the method will have no relation to the correct index in the initial array `arr`.

Suppose, for example, that `arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]` and `target = 6`. In this case the method will return `0` (rather than `5`) as the index of the target element. That's because `arr` will progressively become `arr[3..6]`, `arr[4..6]`, `arr[5..6]` and `arr[6]`, at which point index `0` will be returned.

Here is one way the method could be written, using a `case` statement. The method assumes that `target` is an element of `arr` and (as required by binary searches) the elements of `arr` are ordered, smallest to largest.

```
def recursive_binary_search(arr, target, min_index=0, max_index=arr.size-1)
  mid_index = (min_index+max_index)/2
  case arr[mid_index] <=> target
  when  0  # arr[mid_index] == target
    mid_index
  when -1  # arr[mid_index] < target
    min_index = mid_index + 1
    recursive_binary_search(arr, target, min_index, max_index)
  when  1  # arr[mid_index] > target
    max_index = mid_index - 1
    recursive_binary_search(arr, target, min_index, max_index)
  end
end

arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

arr.each { |target| puts "#{target}: #{recursive_binary_search(arr, target)}" }
1: 0
2: 1
3: 2
4: 3
5: 4
6: 5
```

Comment: To reproduce the error: `arr  =  [0,1]`, `target = 2`

Answer (score 0):

If your arrays are sorted you could try something like this:

```
def search(arr, target)
 return nil if array.empty?
 
 mid_index = array.length / 2

 case target <=> array[mid_index]
 when -1
   search(array.take(mid_index), target)
 when 0
   mid_index
 when 1
   subs = search(array.drop(mid_index + 1), target)
   subs.nil? ? nil : (mid_index + 1) + subs
 end

end
```