# Weird binary search behavior in Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, search

I am trying to implement a recursive binary search in Ruby from scratch.

This is my code:

```
class Searcher

    def get_limits(array)
        [0, array.length - 1]
    end
    
    def binary_search_recursive(array, key)

        low, high = get_limits(array)
    
        mid = (low + high) / 2
    
        return -1 if low > high
    
        return binary_search_recursive(array[low, mid-1], key) if (array[mid] > key)
    
        return binary_search_recursive(array[mid+1, high], key) if (array[mid] < key)
    
        return mid if (array[mid] == key)
    
    end
    
end     

arr = [1,3,4,12,16,21,34,45,55,76,99,101]
key = 34
s = BinarySearch.new
index = s.binary_search_recursive(arr, key)
puts index
```

When I put 'key' as 21, it weirdly gives me the right intended answer, the index 5. Arguably, I also get the right answer when 'key' = 3, but I suspect it's by chance.

You see, whenever 'key' != 21 or 3, I get either -1, 0, 1 or 2 for every element of the array.
What in the world am I doing wrong?

I've tried several different recursive binary search versions found online, this is just the most recent one. I feel like I get the same issue every time?

Comment: You shouldn't be slicing the array to create new arrays for two reasons:  1) it's expensive; and  2) you lose the context of where the sub-array was in the parent array.

Comment: @pjs Helpful! This was also the reason why none of my implementations worked; I insisted on adding slicing to shorten the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you ask for after I edited my question. Problem with the code was you were splitting into new array so 34 was the only element at that array at the end therefore index was 0.

```
class Searcher
    def binary_search(array, val, low=0, high=(length - 1))
        return nil if high < low
        mid = (low + high) >> 1
        case val <=> array[mid]
          when -1
            binary_search(array, val, low, mid - 1)
          when 1
            binary_search(array, val, mid + 1, high)
          else mid
        end
     end
end     

arr = [1,3,4,12,16,21,34,45,55,76,99,101]
key = 34
s = Searcher.new
index = s.binary_search(arr, key, 0, arr.length)
puts index
```

Comment: I want to create the method within a Searcher class full of searching methods. Does it really have to be within an Array class for it to work? I tried implementing your fix but with an array 'array' as parameter, and I still get the same error.

Comment: If you put this method in Array class you can use like: `index = array.binary_search(key)` or you can modify by adding array as parameter and changing `case val <=> self[mid]` to `case val <=> array[mid]` and for each recursion you should narrow down the array.

Comment: You can also check built-in binary search method from here: https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Array:bsearch_index

Comment: Thank you, but I specifically tried to implement it from scratch. I found a working solution from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52155992/recursive-binary-search-in-ruby

Comment: This is a great implementation but it doesn't really explain the problems with OP's code. OP is chopping up the array in the recursive calls, so it loses context for where the found index was relative to the original array. There is nothing wrong with `/ 2`--it's the same as `>> 1`.